# How can I make Timestamp Protobuff back to my timezone since the github version of timestamp is deprecated?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc, grpc-go

Alright so I just realized something when I generate new protobuff file using:

```
protoc my_file.proto --go_out=./
```

My .proto struct is somehow looks like:

```
message MyRequest {
 google.protobuf.Timestamp my_time = 1;
}
```

If I use the protoc command somewhere around in 2021 I would get:

```
import timestamp "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp"

type MyRequest struct {
    MyTime *timestamp.Timestamp `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=my_time,json=myTime,proto3" json:"my_time,omitempty"`
}
```

But now I 'll get:

```
import timestamppb "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb"
    
type MyRequest struct {
    MyTime *timestamppb.Timestamp `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=my_time,json=myTime,proto3" json:"my_time,omitempty"`
}
```

The main problem is that the old struct presents **MyTime in my timezone**, but the new one **converts it to UTC+0**. Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure? `protobuf` serialization of a time does not store timezone information (in the two types you reference). Times are all converted to `UTC` before serialization.

Answer (score 1):

You can see [this](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go/blob/b92717ecb630d4a4824b372bf98c729d87311a4d/types/known/timestamppb/timestamp.pb.go#L206) method is call `.UTC()` method.

Looking from that method, you can create custom function to return time for your time zone.

this is the example :

```golang
func ForMyTimeZone(x *timestamppb.Timestamp) time.Time {
    return time.Unix(int64(x.GetSeconds()), int64(x.GetNanos()))
}
```